# cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)

Tags: django

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://aas-system.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webpush/urls.py, line 1, in <module>
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages'
]
Server time:    Tue, 01 Feb 2022 07:52:34 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django 4.0 and higher then `django.conf.urls.url()` is removed.

You can use [re_path[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re_path) in case of `url`, which also use `regex` as `url`.

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.your_view_name),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Django 4. In this version, `url from django.conf.url` no longer works.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url

So you have two options.

Use something below Django 3.2. I suspect that what you are doing on your local version. FYI, using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your local environment is a good way to save your configuration and it can simplify the installation in other env.

Or update your code. You should then try `re_path`in order to do so

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re-path